# How to communicate with printer from ruby language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, printing

I want to communicate with printer by using ruby language. i am using socket programming to communicate with printer. my printer ip is "192.168.24.687" and port number is "20000".

Below is the code that i am using to communicate with printer

```
require 'socket'
sock = TCPSocket.new('192.168.24.687', 20000)
sock.write 'MARK START'
sock.close
```

In the above code i am sending "MARK START" command to the printer which will turn printer ON , but it's not working. with above code i am able to established connection with remote server but not able to send "MARK START" command.

But the same is working with putty. with putty i am using connection type as `"raw"` and connecting to the printer.After connection is successful i can send command "MARK START" to putty and able to turn on printer.

I want to know why my code is not able to send "MARK START" command to printer??

Thanks,
Sanjay Salunkhe

Comment: I guess you need to use `puts` instead of `write` to also include a new line at the end of the message.

Comment: If you're using the socket to send a single string, you could use open with a block to avoid having to explicitly close the socket.  If you execute this in a shell: `nc -l 9999` then you can test socket clients in another shell, e.g. in irb: `TCPSocket.open('localhost', 9999) { |s| s << "Hi" }`.

Comment: @BoraMa - I tried puts instead of write but still not working.. here is the command that i tried... sock.puts 'MARK START\n'

Comment: Nono, either try `sock.write "MARK START\n"` or `sock.puts 'MARK START'`. Note the difference in quotes: double quotes will send `\n` as a special character (new line) whereas single quotes will send it verbatim which is not what you want.

Comment: @BoraMa - Still not working . I tried sock.write "MARK START\n" and it is returning value 11 and sock.puts 'MARK START' it returns nil value.

Comment: Well, the return values are not that relevant (`write` just returns the number of bytes written, `puts` returns `nil`). So that fact that it still does not work means that the problem is in something else. What kind of protocol for communicating with the printer is that anyway?

Comment: printer is using dynmark 3 protocol. i don't know much about this protocol. But my general question is if we can connect with putty with "raw" connection type then we should be able to connect it with ruby socket programming. I don't know why socket programming is not working.